# No Read/Write Permission as User on a Secondary Drive

Tags: permissions, files, drive, read-only

I have a 2nd hard drive that is used for data only, it has been formatted both in NTFS and FAT32, the system is dual booted with Windows so the Data drive is used to share data between Win and Ubuntu.

However in Ubuntu with the user account set as limited user, I cannot do anything with the files, namely create files, edit names, move them, modify etc. But I can do all that fine with the Admin account.

I've tried changing permissions, ownership, installing ntfs plugins etc. Nothing seems to work. Didn't have this problem in the old Ubuntu 10.04. I'm currently running on 12.04 LTS

Cheers

Comment: How do you mount your drive? If it is via `/etc/fstab`, please post the relevant line(s) for this drive.

Comment: Please most the messages from `mount` and post the contents of your `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Take a look here: [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions). Install ntfs-conifg tool and enable read-write access.

Comment: Hi I had a line in fstab automoutning the partition on boot, have removed this but the original problem was needing the admin password to mount the partition as user. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution:

- Run 'gksu nautilus' (use 'Ctrl+alt+T' for quick access to terminal)
- Go to the /media folder in the file system.
- Then right click the drive, and go into properties
- Under the permissions tab change the permissions to
  read/write, and make sure 'owner' and 'group' are set to "your user name" instead of "root".
- Then click "Apply permissions to enclosed folders."

(you may have to 'sudo apt-get install nautilus')

You should be able to access the folder from your user account without root access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Mounting Windows Partitions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions) from the [Ubuntu community wiki?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

**Name: ntfs-config**

Install ntfs-config package either from Ubuntu Software Center or via terminal with this command

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
```

Then call it from Dash by writing **ntfs config** and mark the box with "Enable write support"

This should work as well for internal HDD.

[image: NTFSConfig]

**Another tool** you can install is a GUI program for fstab.

**BE CAREFUL** with this program , you can corrupt your system very easy.

**Name: Storage Device Manager.**

Search it by name in Ubuntu Software Center

or install it via terminal with this command

```
sudo apt-get install pysdm
```

Call it from Dash by writing **Device Manager** and from there you can manage, how your HDD will behavior.

[image: pysdm]